# get original dynamic link domain in android app

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I would like to read the original dynamic link domain and the shortened url value for example from:
https://APPID.app.goo.gl/XYZT

It is possible to create different domains for a dynamic link in firebase and I use these for identification purpose.

On iOS the dynamic link is handled in

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  //Get the original domain from url variable, but shortened path cannot be fetched as well on iOS -> if anybody knows how this is done, I appreciate any tips
}
```

and I can find the domain APPID.app.goo.gl but not the path afterwards

and on Android

```
  FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
  .getDynamicLink(getIntent())
  .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
  })
  .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
       @Override
       public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
            // pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink(); //deep link but not dynamic link value
       }
  });
```

How can i get these values on Android (domain + path) and iOS(path) form the original link?